Pressure Sensitivity Not Working w/ XP-Pen Tablet (Blender 4.2)
For reference I am using an XP-Pen Artist Pro Gen 2 drawing tablet.
As the title states I am having issues with trying to use pressure sensitivity within Blender using my XP-Pen tablet. I have seen a lot of workarounds on here and through other sources mainly focused on Wacom, but I’ve tried those workarounds to see if I would be able to fix this.
This includes uninstalling and reinstalling the tablet drivers, uninstalling and reinstalling Blender, specifying what type of API Blender should use both within Blender Preferences and my tablet driver, and even doing the unplugging and plugging back in that is recommended in Blender’s User Manual.
Has anyone else run into this issue with an XP-Pen tablet, or any other tablet really,  and been able to come up with a solution? I’m really running on fumes here with trial and error and would appreciate any additional assistance!!

You have turned the pressure sensitivity on with the desired brush parameter, yes?

Yes I have the pressure sensitivity toggled on for the strength of the brush, so I toggled it off for the size of the brush.

I just managed to solve it! I went into the Task Manager for my PC and changed the administrator properties in Blender. That finally got it working for me.
So Blender should not be run as an administrator in order for the pressure sensitivity to work with my XP Pen tablet.
This was also all done after I had uninstalled the XP-Pen Tablet drivers using Command Prompts, so if the administrator change does not work immediately it may be due to drivers as well.
